# Tropical islands, Berlin, Germany. Inflatable "toys"?

Tags: germany, local-knowledge

Me and my family are going to Tropical Islands in a few weeks and my three year old wants to bring his inflatable submarine, is that allowed?

[image]

I tried to find something on their [webpage](https://www.tropical-islands.de/en/visitor-information/content-a-z/) but I couldn't see anything.

Looking at pictures and videos from the place shows nothing inflatable which leads me to believe that it's not permitted.

Does anyone know for sure if that is the case?

Comment: Why don't you write an email to welcome@tropical-islands.de ?

Comment: I've found mentions of sleeping on air mattresses and a picture with some kind of inflatable boat (not unlike your submarine) in the background. No official mention though

Comment: @MichelKeijzers while I do agree that is a way to get an answer I also do believe this question could be of value to others. I could email, call or write a letter, but that still means there is a "void" on information that could be useful here. Someone here maybe works there, knows someone who do, have been there and seen something (a sign or that others has inflatables) or perhaps someone is there right now and wants to answer this question to earn some internet points and don't mind asking the staff. I don't find this question any different than visa questions which also can be emailed about

Comment: @npst thank you! I have not seen a single picture like that. You must have some nice Google skills

Comment: @Andreas Please review the Help file here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask The help page sets forth the expectation that participants in SE:Travel will conduct some research of their own, and report to the community what they've found. You can (and should, I think) email the resort, and ask. If they send a response, you can post it here to help everyone.

Comment: @David **that sets for the expectation that participants here will conduct some research of their own, and report on what they've found.** Which I did. In the question I said I read on their webpage and found nothing.

Comment: Why are you resisting asking them by email?

Comment: I'm not. I'm using this webpage for what it's for. Nothing else. I have done what is expected from an asker as far as I can see. My question is not much different than as I said before, visa questions which can also be answered by emailing an embassy.

Comment: @Andreas Maybe it was more of a language- than a google-fu-thing: https://www.vice.com/de/article/43xz9d/ich-habe-24-stunden-im-tropical-island-verbracht

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are allowed. They even sell them in the shop there:

> They are! And they sell them in one of their shops if you don’t have your own. They even have a pump in the same shop to blow them up if you want. I’m sure you could use it to blow your own inflatables up too but I don’t know. Prices are very reasonable! I got a giant pineapple (can fit 2 on) for about €30

(Source: [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/FAQ_Answers-g1184878-d567173-t5636868-Does_anyone_know_if_inflatables_are_allowed.html))

Also confirmed by emailing them:

> Inflatables are allowed. The usage might be restricted depending on the life guards and the number of guests in the water.